# How to display something if the condition is true in Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1

I'm new to magento 2. Correct me If I'm wrong in the title I've made for this thread.

I have a problem in my condition about a specific attribute for a product.
I want to show a content when product attribute promo_banner is set to yes.

Here's my code:

```
<?php if ( ($parent_category->getParentId() == 40 ) && ($_product->getAttributeText('promo_banner'))) :?>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 container-of-text-banner">
                    <label class="promo-banner-here">
                        Save when ordering case quantities!! Extra 20% Savings
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Thanks,
MazeStricks

Comment: Try with if condition ( ($parent_category->getParentId() == 40 ) && (!empty($_product->getAttributeText('promo_banner')) && $_product->getAttributeText('promo_banner' != ''))

Comment: Thanks for the comment Rakesh you're so good. I'll try this one

Comment: Thank you so much Rakesh for the effort answering my question. Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **eav_attribute** table, the product attribute *Yesno* values are stored as '**int**' (backend_type) so you should try with:

```
if ( ($parent_category->getParentId() == 40 ) && ($_product->getData('promo_banner') == 1))
```

Comment: Hi WaPoNe, I'll try this also thanks for your answer

Comment: Hi Guys and also WaPone, I tried your approach this works best on me. Thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to not hard code category ID's. That is a bad practice as in some scenarios they can change.

```
<?php if ((bool)$_product->getAttributeText('promo_banner'))) :?>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 container-of-text-banner">
                    <label class="promo-banner-here">
                        Save when ordering case quantities!! Extra 20% Savings
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Hi Andre thanks for a very informative approach. I will avoid hard coding the ID's in the future projects. I'll try this approach also.

Comment: Hi Andre I tried also this approach of yours but it did not work in my end. but anyway thank you for your effort answering my question. :)

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it will help others to remind also them that it's not proper to hard code category ID's. Thanks for this